# FirebaseAnalytics log screen_view automatically with class:null only without debugging after succesfully manual log screen_view

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, logging

Hello I'm using FirebaseAnalytics to log screen_views when user clicks on some fragments, but automatically logs these screen views on Activitys.
I'm tracking the screen_view logging like this:

```
analyticsData.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, PageKeyAnalytics.HOME_SCREEN)
        analyticsData.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_CLASS, this::class.java.name)
        oxxolytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SCREEN_VIEW, analyticsData).onFirebase()
```

And this is successfully there is no problem, but suddenly in my console starts to appear automatic logging events like this:

```
Logging screen view with name, class: null, HomeActivity
10-05 09:50:06.157 V/FA-SVC  ( 2762): Logging event: origin=app,name=screen_view(_vs),params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=app, engagement_time_msec(_et)=143, ga_previous_class(_pc)=HomeActivity, ga_previous_id(_pi)=941706220730328938, ga_screen_class(_sc)=HomeActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=941706220730328939, manual_tracking(_mst)=1}]
10-05 09:50:06.178 V/FA-SVC  ( 2762): Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 2198519
10-05 09:50:06.178 V/FA-SVC  ( 2762): Unscheduling upload
10-05 09:50:06.181 V/FA-SVC  ( 2762): Scheduling upload, millis: 2198519
10-05 09:50:06.184 V/FA-SVC  ( 2762): Background event processing time, ms: 27
10-05 09:50:06.189 E/FA      (30029): Name is reserved. Type, name: event, user_engagement
10-05 09:50:06.189 E/FA      (30029): Invalid event name. Event will not be logged (FE): user_engagement
```

But even weirder this only happen when I'm not debbuging the app, only when I install and start to using.

I already have this on my manifest

```
<meta-data
            android:name="google_analytics_automatic_screen_reporting_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
```

So I don't know what is happening.
What could it be?

Comment: I found the error, this occurs because in the code my partner added Google Tag Manager, and this was failing, so GTM is sending this error logs